# Change of Color in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let G be a planar graph with edges colored red and blue. Show that there is a vertex $x$ such that going around the edges incident to $x$ in clockwise order we encounter no more than two changes of color.

How do you attack such a problem? Is it by induction?

Comment: I think your question was answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114955/if-edges-of-g-are-two-colored-then-there-is-a-vertex-of-g-with-at-most-two?rq=1

Comment: It was asked there but not answered.  Yes, I would attempt to prove this by induction.

Comment: It is, however, answered here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541651/a-bicolored-plane-graph-contains-a-vertex-with-low-oscillation?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A bicolored plane graph contains a vertex with low oscillation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541651/a-bicolored-plane-graph-contains-a-vertex-with-low-oscillation)